# How to get the name of a MenuItem which is clicked in a MenuButton

Tags: java, javafx, onclick, menuitem

I'm trying to get the name of a MenuItem and then set a Label text to the name of this clicked MenuItem in a MenuButton. How can i do this? The MenuItems getting the id's from a String in a DB.

Variables:

```
@FXML
private MenuButton projektAuswahl;

MenuItem item;
```

Creating new MenuItem:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

while (rs.next()) {
    item = new MenuItem(rs.getString(1));
    item.setId(rs.getString(1));
    projektAuswahl.getItems().add(item);
}
```

set the Label text:

```
private void setProjectLabel() {
        //projectnameLabel.setText(item.getText()); //not working..
    }
```

How can i recognize which MenuItem is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to register a handler for the [`onAction` event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#onActionProperty). This could be a new one for each `MenuItem` saving the data about the text each, or you could access the [event source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#source) to get a reference to the `MenuItem`:

```
static MenuItem createMenuItem(String text, EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler) {
    MenuItem result = new MenuItem(text);
    result.setOnAction(handler);
    return result;
}

private Label projectnameLabel;

private void setProjectLabel(ActionEvent event) {
    MenuItem source = (MenuItem) event.getSource();
    projectnameLabel.setText(source.getText());
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = this::setProjectLabel;

    MenuButton btn = new MenuButton("menu");
    btn.getItems().addAll(createMenuItem("a", handler),
            createMenuItem("b", handler),
            createMenuItem("c", handler));

    projectnameLabel = new Label();

    VBox root = new VBox(10, btn, projectnameLabel);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add action listener directly in code like :

```
    menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            setProjectLabel(); // in your case
        }
    });
```

Or I propose you to add a controller to your fxml, then replace all code you displayed in it and bind the setProjectLabel() with the menuitem in SceneBuilder here :

[image]

Comment: The MenuItems don't exist if there are no Datas in the DB. It's not possible.

Comment: Yes, you can create the Menuitem and add the Action Handler like fabian said. By the way, if you don't use scenebuilder, why add @FXML?